# How to hide order index of variations in Patternlab using Handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, patternlab.io

I am using indexes to order Patterns. As recommended I am putting some spaces between the pattern indexes in case i would like to reorder some later.
I am naming the files like shown in https://patternlab.io/docs/reorganizing-patterns/.

[image]

It does work. As you can see in the next screenshot, the index is also shown in the rendered page. **Is there a way to hide it or am I doing something wrong? Is there maybe a different approach using Handlebars (.hbs) files?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to migrate to the newest patternlab version and use the „order“ property introduced to get set via .md files, compare to the new content on the page you mentioned in your post.

Comment: Thank you. I can try that out some day